# How to use auto-generated ToDescriptionString method

Tags: mudblazor

After updating Mudblazor to Version 6.2.0 i get following Warning:

[CS0618] "EnumExtensions.ToDescriptionString(Enum)" is obsolete: "Please use the auto-generated ToDescriptionString method instead or implement your own extension method."

How can I use the auto-genrated ToDescriptionString method and where to find it?

I haven't found anything about auto-generated methods in the documentation on Mudblazor.com.

Answer (score 0):

The "Please use the auto-generated ToDescriptionString method" message is for contributors in the project.
You can create your own extension by copying theirs.
[MudBlazor repo](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Extensions/EnumExtensions.cs)

Create your own `EnumExtensions.cs` then add the code below.

```
using System.ComponentModel; 

public static class EnumExtensions
{

    public static string ToDescriptionString(this Enum value)
    {
        var field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        if (field is null)
        {
            return value.ToString().ToLower();
        }

        var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];

        return attributes is { Length: > 0 }
            ? attributes[0].Description
            : value.ToString().ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: What value is there in that when we previously had a public version that did the same thing?

Comment: @user15716642 Apparently it's for performance enhancements. https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/6098

Comment: Makes sense. It just kind of stinks because they should've made it internal if it wasn't meant for us to use. I wouldn't have even used the description attribute (as opposed to DisplayName), personally, if it didn't seem to be the MudBlazor standard :/